# Aggregate rows according to JSON array content

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a PSQL table with json tags, that are always strings stored in a json array :

```
id     |  tags (json)
--------------------------
1      | ["tag1", "tag2"]
2      | ["tag12", "tag2"]
122    | []
```

I would like to query, for  instance, the count of entries in the table containing each tag.

For instance, I'd like to get :

```
tag         |  count
--------------------------
tag1        | 1
tag2        | 2
tag12       | 1
```

I tried

```
SELECT tags::text AS tag, COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM my_table GROUP BY tag;
```

but if does not work, since it gives

```
tag                |  cnt
--------------------------
["tag1", "tag2"]   | 1
["tag12", "tag2"]  | 1
```

I guess I need to get the list of all tags in an inner query, and then for each tag count the rows that contain this tag, but I can't find how to do that. Can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json[b]_array_elements_text()` and a lateral join to unnest the array:

```
select x.tag, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
cross join lateral json_array_elements_text(t.tags) as x(tag)
group by x.tag
```

Comment: I think `json_array_elements_text()` would be better - especially if the columns **is** a `json` and not `jsonb` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: indeed... Thanks.